# How to say - Fine, don't listen to me

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I have been wondering about this for quite some time. Let's say you are having an argument with someone. Perhaps it goes something like this,

> A: If we do things your way, we are going to have problems! It's not going to work
>
> B: No, I'm absolutely right. I'm going to do it my way. No matter what you say.

At which point A realizes it is fruitless to fight B anymore, gives up and says

> A: Fine, don't (listen to me/do what I say/listen to sound advice)! And don't come crying to me when it blows up in your face.

My question, is how would you say, "Fine, don't listen to me!" Clearly A doesn't actually want B to listen to him. so I feel that `だったら、僕に聞かないでくれ`　doesn't really work. Maybe more like `聞かないでごらん`?

Another time I've wanted to say this is when I call someone to let them know something important, and they don't pick up the phone. At which point I sarcastically say, "Ok fine, don't pick up the phone. I guess I won't tell you the important news..."

Comment: Not an answer, but in those situations I have been known to say: `別にあんたのため電話してるんじゃないけどね。`  It's really rude, so I wouldn't use it in front of anyone that is a mutual friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Fine, don't (listen to me/do what I say/listen to sound advice)! And don't come crying to me when it blows up in your face.

I would say something like...

> あっそ！じゃ｛[勝手]{かって}に / 好きに / 好きなように｝すれば！[後]{あと}で｛[泣]{な}きついたって /  泣きついてきたって｝[知]{し}らないからね！